# HTML month spin boxes

Tags: html, forms

How do I make a month spin box using just HTML? I'm looking for something on the lines of:

```
<input type="number" min="10" max="20" />
```

Except months instead of numbers.

Comment: No way using HTML. Use JS to make some wrapper and simulate "spin" feature.

Comment: Are you talking about arrow on the right side to select date??

Comment: Yes, Im talking about that. But I want both up and down arrows, not only up.

Comment: can you explain me in brief

Comment: there are three arrows up and down to increment and decrements and one big arrow for month, do you need all these 3

Comment: I need only up down arrows in the side. No need drop down for month.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use input type=month. This is currenty unsupported by major browsers.

You need to create one on your own or use a ready solution, like something for jQuery.

This question has been discussed here: [month selection dropdown in html, javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928785/month-selection-dropdown-in-html-javascript)